# How to install KDE without Ruby?

Tags: centos, kde, ruby

For a project I'm using Ruby 2.3.1,

I'm using a CentOS7 OS with ruby 2.3.1 installed. When I run `yum install kde-workspace` it installs/downgrades to `ruby 2.0.0.648-29.el7` which makes the application unusable.

Is it possible to skip dependencies when installing KDE?

Answer (score 0):

Install kde with the required dependencies , then use [`rvm`](https://github.com/rvm/rvm) Ruby Version Manager to install the 2.3.1 version:

```
rvm install ruby-2.3.1
```

set it as default:

```
rvm --default use 2.3.1
```

Comment: I'm behind a horrible proxy that does not allow rvm.

Comment: Try this tuto https://rvm.io/workflow/proxy

Comment: I've installed RVM offline, the proxy is being managed by some evil overlord that won't budge on his whitelist. So not much help there. On my system I have ruby-2.3.1 installed in `/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby` is it possible by using RVM to point to that folder instead of `/usr/bin/ruby`?